# Place text underneath product images WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to add text beneath the product gallery images of my Wordpress Woo-commerce site.

I have attempted to use the general scripts found online:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );

function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
   echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="background: #fdfd5a; padding: 1em 2em">';
   echo '<span>THIS IS A TEST. YOU CAN ADD TEXT, IMAGES AND ANY HTML</span>';
   echo '</div>';
}
```

You can see in the following screenshot that the text appears here and not beneath the actual image[image]

The website link this is referencing can be found at: https://www.tattiniboots.com/product/retriever/

Update:
After trying the proposed solution below, the div text shows all the way at the bottom:[image]

I am attempting to get this div to appear here:
[image]

The link I am working at is found here: https://www.tattiniboots.com/product/terranova/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add style `clear:both` in your `div`. check the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );

function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
   echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="background: #fdfd5a; padding: 1em 2em; clear:both;">';
   echo '<span>THIS IS A TEST. YOU CAN ADD TEXT, IMAGES AND ANY HTML</span>';
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Please see edits, this still does not work appropriately

Comment: @user2592356 do you want that text exactly below the image?